# sqlite & flex - insert into or ignore problem

Tags: sqlite, apache-flex, insert

I'm using flex to develop my first desktop app and I'm working with sqlite for the first time as well.

I'm creating my database and all the tables just fine, but I would also like to add a few rows of data into a couple of the tables so the information is present on first install.

The only problem I'm having is every time I run the program it keeps inserting the same data over and over again.

here's what I'm trying, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
            stmt.text = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl_breed ("+" breed_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+"  breed_breed TEXT)";
            stmt.execute();
            stmt.text = "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO tbl_breed (breed_breed)"+" VALUES ('Test')";
            stmt.execute();
```

thanks!

Comment: It's better to edit your original question to improve the likehood if it being answered. I've updated my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203898/sqlite-flex-insert-into-if-not-exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so i figured it out... I guess you have to hard code the the primary key id value.

here what I had to do.

```
            stmt.text = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl_breed ("+" breed_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+"  breed_breed TEXT)";
            stmt.execute();
            stmt.text = "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO tbl_breed (breed_id,breed_breed)"+" VALUES ('1','test')";
            stmt.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

you may also want to use parameter with  queries. like

```
stmt.text = "insert into Mobile_gps_photo_data (GPS_LAT,GPS_LON,_PHOTO) values (:B,:C)";
    stmt.parameters[":B"]=B;
    stmt.parameters[":C"]=C;
        stmt.execute();
```